# Virtual parent and child relationship

Tags: c++

The code snippets underneath are from my `Keyboard.h` and `Keyboard.cpp`. My question is, how would i implement a layered parent and child relationship? So that if the child dose not implement any of the virtual members, the parent may be free to do so. As an example, the child implements KeyboardDepressA but dose not implement KeyboardDepressB, leaving the parent to implement the catch for KeyboardDepressB. Also parent and child are of course of different types and what not...

I don't want the child to know about the parents' support for `Device::Keyboard`; therefor, i wanted to call the parent using get instance as see in the `KeyboardDepressB`. In order to make this work, i need to assign the parent to the `static` instance itself but `static` dose not have support for the key word `this`. So what should i do?

I kept the code to the minimum. If more is needed please feel free to ask. ^^

```
class Keyboard
{

private:

    Keyboard ();
    ~Keyboard ();

public:

    static Device::Keyboard& Instance();
    static void SetParent(Device::Keyboard *cpParent);

    virtual void    KeyboardDepressA    ();
    virtual void    KeyboardReleaseA    ();

    virtual void    KeyboardDepressB    ();
    virtual void    KeyboardReleaseB    ();

    …   …   ...
};


Device::Keyboard&
Keyboard::Instance()
{

    static Device::Keyboard nrKeyboard;
    return nrKeyboard;

} // member

void
Keyboard::SetParent(Device::Keyboard *cpParent)
{

    Device::Keyboard& nrParent(Keyboard::Instance());
    *this = cpParent;

} // member

void
Keyboard::KeyboardDepressA()
{

    Device::Keyboard& nrParent(Keyboard::Instance());
    nrParent.KeyboardDepressA();

} // member

void
Keyboard::KeyboardReleaseA()
{

    Device::Keyboard& nrParent(Keyboard::Instance());
    nrParent.KeyboardReleaseA();

} // member

void
Keyboard::KeyboardDepressB()
{

    Device::Keyboard& nrParent(Keyboard::Instance());
    nrParent.KeyboardDepressB();

} // member

void
Keyboard::KeyboardReleaseB()
{

    Device::Keyboard& nrParent(Keyboard::Instance());
    nrParent.KeyboardReleaseB();

} // member
```

Comment: singleton classes typically make their constructors/destructors private

Comment: ty. i know... this is still work in progress.. i'm going to have to make it singleton if i choose to use the instance design. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in general it's complicated to mix inheritance with the singleton pattern so be cautious there.

If you have a parent child relationship, in C++ the parent and/or the child can implement a virtual function.

If you want the parent to implement it and not the child: declare it virtual in the parent and implement for the parent but do not declare or implement it for the child

```
class parent
{
public:
    virtual void func();
}
void parent::func(){ ... }
class child : public parent
{
};
parent* p = new child;
p->func(); // calls parent's func
```

If you want a parent implementation that is overridden by the child: declare it as virtual in both parent and child classes and implement it for both classes (note the child can call the parent's implementation without having to understand what the implementation is)

```
class parent
{
public:
    virtual void func();
}
void parent::func(){ ... }
class child : public parent
{
    virtual void func();
};
void child::func(){ ... parent::func();}
parent* p = new child;
p->func(); // calls child's func
```

If you want the child to implement it and the parent to not: declare it as a pure virtual member in the parent and declare and implement it for the child

```
class parent
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
}
class child : public parent
{
    virtual void func();
};
void child::func(){ ... }
parent* p = new child;
p->func(); // calls child's func
```

Comment: lol. i didn't think to inherit the parent as you have here `class child : public parent`, i'm being too focused on delegation patterns. also i may have realized my problem, in that i could do `static Device::Keyboard *npKeyboard;` `return npKeyboard;` rather than reference.

Comment: the reference style you're doing above is cleaner imo. i'd recommend against using the pointer if you're going to dynamically allocate the singleton because you'll have to delete it somewhere which is always a messy when dealing with singletons